# memory leak in ajax - setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an ajax code which causes memory leak (especially in IE).

```
function setStatus() {             
    var formInput=$(this).serialize(); 
    $.getJSON('CheckStatus.action', formInput, function(data) {                                   
            if(data == false) {    
                function getEventsPeriodicaly() {
                    getEvents();
                };

                var timer = setInterval(function () {getEventsPeriodicaly();}, 5000);
            }
        }
    );
} 

function getEvents() {
    var formInput=$(this).serialize(); 
    $.getJSON('StartEP.action', formInput,function(data) {                 
       var txt = $("#txtEventsArea");             
       if(data != null && data.toString().length!=0) {                                                    
         txt.val(data.join('\n') + '\n' +  txt.val()); 
         data=null;
       } 
    }
)}
```

StartEP

```
public String startEP() throws Exception {
    logger.info("[EP] In startEP");
    try { 
        synchronized(status) {
            if(!getStatus()) {     
                EventProcessor amiep = EventProcessor.getInstance();                             
                amiep.addObserver(this);
                new Thread(amiep).start();                                           
                setStatus(true);                
            }            
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {     
         logger.error("Unable to start EP", ex);                 
         return ERROR;                 
    }
    logger.info("[EP] In startEP, before loop");
    while(!gotNewData) {
        Thread.sleep(4000);                        
    }            
    gotNewData = false;
    logger.info("[EP] Out startEP");
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The StartEP action returns messages (about 5KB on each request). First I thought it concerned with setting text to textarea, but after some tests got that it is not the reason. Could it be setInterval method?
Is there any considerations?
thanks

Comment: off-topic: why do you have `getEvents` wrapped in __two__ extra functions in your `setInterval`?  `setInterval(getEvents, 5000)`.  On-topic: I don't see anything that should be leaking in that

Comment: there is another function who will also call getEvents in future.

Comment: what does that have to do with wrapping `getEvents` twice?

Comment: it definitely has leak. If I let the explorer running all the night it wastes more than 1 GB RAM, though it starts with 30Mb ... it is weird

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw two calls on getEvents...

Comment: If its eating up all that active memory then I'm willing to bet the problem resides in the web service you are calling. Can you post the code for StartEP.action?

Comment: setInverval( __function__ (){ __getEventsPeriodicaly__ (); }, 500); <-- two extra functions.   I believe you that it has a leak, just saying I don't see anything in ___this___ code that should leak.  You're not doing anything else on a timer?

Comment: Got it... didn't pay attention. u r right, but it is not an issue.

Comment: You are wrapping getEvents inside two extra functions. Why are you placing getEvents() within a function to begin with? And why are you encapsulating that function within yet another function in your setInterval call?

Comment: Post the code for the web services. If you've got a memory leak I sincerely doubt it is within this code and even if it is you can use developer tools to look at allocated memory on a page and go from there. Javascript would be pretty difficult to get a memory leak in as well, I'd imagine whatever SSSL you're using is the culprit.

Comment: What does a leak in the web services possibly have to do with IE chewing up memory?!?  If there's a leak in IE, it's in IE -- ___in client side code___

Answer (score 0):

I would say this looks pretty suspect:

```
while(!gotNewData) {
    Thread.sleep(4000);                        
}
```

Where is gotNewData set? If you call the web service once and set gotNewData to true and then call another web service and set gotNewData to false I don't think there is a guarantee that you're setting the variable within the same instance of the application. Therefore, if you are not, then every time you're hitting the web service you are starting a new thread and then continually putting it back to sleep.

Comment: gotNewData is static, so that is not an issue

Comment: Static or not, is your call guaranteed to hit the same instance of the application on subsequent web service calls? If it is not then you're entering an infinite loop every time you call the service.

Comment: and this anyway this part is on server side, it has nothing to do with client RAM usage. the memory problem is on client side and IE is wasting that memory, not java.

Comment: sure it is guaranteed, that's why I use synchronization block and singleton instance.